# Ruby regex for text within parentheses

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a regex to replace all terms in parentheses unless the parentheses are within square brackets.

e.g.

```
(matches) #match
[(do not match)] #should not match
[[does (not match)]] #should not match
```

I current have:

```
[^\]]\([^()]*\) #Not a square bracket, an opening bracket, any non-bracket character and a closing bracket.
```

However this is still matching words within the square brackets.

I have also created a rubular page of my progress so far:  http://rubular.com/r/gG22pFk2Ld

Comment: Bit of a tough one. The double sets of square-brackets will require recursion (at least once) to match up all the pairs. Definitely possible with a more advanced Regex library that Ruby has (hello Perl fans!). I have a feeling you might have to settle for passing this through multiple sets of ruby regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex is not going to cut it for you if you can nest the square brackets ([see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)).

I think you can only do this with a regex if (a) you only allow one level of square brackets and (b) you assume all square brackets are properly matched. In that case

```
\([^()]*\)(?![^\[]*])
```

is sufficient - it matches any parenthesised expression *not* followed by an unpaired `]`. You need (b) because of the limitations of negative lookbehind (only fixed length strings in 1.9, and not allowed at all in 1.8), which mean you are stuck matching `(match)]` even if you don't want to.

So basically if you need to nest, or to allow unmatched brackets, you should ditch the regex and look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624) to the question I linked to above.

Comment: This appears to work, even for nested square brackets as the depth of the nesting of the square brackets does not make a difference, the term is still matched.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that is not necessary for my requirements.  The square brackets are always at the start/end.  I should have been more clear in my question.  Thanks for the solution.  :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a type of expression you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461619/in-laymens-terms-what-is-the-pumping-lemma) using a pure-regex approach, because you need to keep track of the current nesting/state_if_in_square_bracket (so you don't have a type 3 language anymore).

However, depending on the exact circumstances, you can parse it with multiple regexes or simple parsers. Example approaches:

- Split into sub-strings, delimited by
  `[`/`[[`or `]`/`]]`, change the state
  when such a square bracket is
  encountered, replace () in a
  sub-string if in
  "not_in_square_bracket" state
- Parse for square brackets (including content), remove & remember them (these are "comments"), now replace all the content in normal brackets and re-add the square brackets stuff (you can remember stuff by using unique temp strings)

The complexity of your solution also depends on the detail if escaping ] is allowed.